Need to search for a string that contains a new line in the middle of the search phrase
I have a very large pdf that I need to extract pages from. The pages that I need to extract always start with a specific phrase and end with a specific phrase. One of the phrases contains a new line in the middle of the phrase.
E.g. PDF page looks like this:
Test
1. Applicability

If I search for Test\n1. Applicability, I do not get the desired result.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] demonstrating what you've tried so far. I'd also hazard a guess that the whitespace before the "1." is why your search query doesn't match.

Use startwith() and endwith()

Are you accessing the PDF file directly, or did you use a PDF library to extract the text?

Since the question has tag python, the solution may be based on PyPDF2 package.

You can use r string with re.search() or re.findall():
import re

p = r"\bTest\n1. Applicability\b"

s = """
Test
1. Applicability

Test
1. Applicability
"""

print(re.search(p, s))
print(re.findall(p, s))


Prints
<re.Match object; span=(1, 22), match='Test\n1. Applicability'>
['Test\n1. Applicability', 'Test\n1. Applicability']


Since the phrases are consistent you could use a Regular Expression with the re module.
import re
re.search("^Test\s*1.*<YourEndPhraseHere>$")

The \s* will match any number of white space characters that are between 'Test' and the rest of the phrase, it'll capture the newline character and any whitespace from formatting.
If you have multiple variations that are consistent you could also use fstrings or string formatting inside the regex string.  Maybe the number after test increases or something similar:
import re
for i in range(1,10):
    re.search(f"^Test\s*{i}.*<YourEndPhraseHere>$")

